# Get clicked Radio Button Values from all the row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid (dhtmlx) with lots of rows. What I am trying to achieve is to get all the values of clicked radio button of each row plus the row id separated by comma and put it into an input box ? The row ids and radio button values are separated by :

The row ids are automatically generated in this format 110014742~01~01

rowId:radioBtnValue, rowId:radioBtnValue, rowId:radioBtnValue

13004238~01~01:02, 110012178~01~01:05, 110014742~01~01:03 --> inside the input box when the radio buttons are clicked.

The column that contains all the radio button and its header had an id of rbBtn_sel

There will be another button when it is clicked will take the values from the input box and save it.

```
function DoRowSaveConfig()  {
 var colIndex=mygrid.getColIndexById("rdBtn_sel");
 var radioBtn = mygrid.getCheckedRows(colIndex);
 var  CommaCount = radioBtn.split(",").length - 1 ;
 for (var i= 0; i<radioBtn.length; i++)
 if (radioBtn[i].checked) {
 var selectedVal = radioBtn[i].value;
             document.getElementById('an.ret.sys.4.').value = selectedVal;
             document.getElementById('an.ret.sys.5.').click();
             } 
             }
              return false;
       };
```

Maybe Jquery will have a better solution. Open to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/ep6JE/

[image: How the table/grid structure with column id]

/**********EDIT**************/

Thanks all, and it works as expected but I may have mislead you. Upon clicking the radio button it needs to get the value of the row id not id(second col). Updated the image.

Row ids are automatically generated in this format 110012178~01~01. Also we are using xml and DHTMLX grid will automatically convert to a table.

```
<rows><row id="13004238~01~01"><cell>James Brown</cell>
<cell>12545</cell>
<cell><![CDATA[<div class="rd"><input type="radio" name="130042380101" value="00"></div>
<div class="rd"><input type="radio" name="1100121780101" value="01"></div>
<div class="rd"><input type="radio" name="130042380101" value="02"></div>
<div class="rd"><input type="radio" name="130042380101" value="03"></div>
<div class="rd"><input type="radio" name="130042380101" value="04"></div>
<div class="rd"><input type="radio" name="130042380101" value="05"></div>
<div class="rd"><input type="radio" name="130042380101" value="06"></div>]]>
</cell>
</row>\</rows>';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt - note it is much simpler than the map and assume you only have radios that you want to handle on the page

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6b3Ln/)

```
$(function() {
  $("input[type=radio]").on("click",function() { 
    var clicked = [];
    $("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function() {
        clicked.push($(this).closest("td").prev().text()+"~"+this.value);
    });
    $("#an\\.ret\\.sys\\.4\\.").val(clicked);
  });    
});
```

If you need the NAME of the radio:

```
clicked.push(this.name+":"+this.value);
```

Comment: Hi! Mplungjan, Thank you for your reply. It works but I may have mislead you. Please see my edit.

Comment: Please see update. There is NOTHING in your html or fiddle that shows me where the rowId is except in the radio name. Can you please update the fiddle with the actual RENDERED html? Looking HERE: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/index.shtml I do not see where the row id is set

Comment: you need http://www.dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxGrid/samples/16_rows_columns_manipulations/02_api_grid.html `alert(mygrid.bB(mygrid.getRowIndex(mygrid.bI())))`

Comment: Hi! I have sorted this out but I seem to get when a null value when it is clicked first time. Can you help ?

Comment: Help how? I do not know what you sorted

Comment: I have updated the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/ep6JE/9/  

I have posted in the dhtmlx forum as well

http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=34634

Comment: But in the fiddle you do not HAVE a grid. Just a table with radios

Comment: Hi!  Can you take a look at this please ? http://forum.dhtmlx.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=34634  
It has the full code.. Maybe you can understand it better

Comment: Where do you call doinitgrid?

Comment: @ mplungjan after the xml loads..However, I have changed the html slightly to get the id from the parent div of the radio button. It seems to work until the radio buttons of more than 2 rows are clicked.  The ids gets updated... http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/PYcH3/5/

Comment: I do not understand your comment - does it work or does it not do what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Hi! I changed the html code slightly so that there is a div with an id surrounding all the radio buttons and use that id instead. Thanks again for the help. Here is what I did at the end.  http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/PYcH3/5/

Answer (score 0):

Use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/BSQbp/)</kbd>

```
function DoRowSaveConfig() {
    var arr = $('table').find('input[type="radio"]:checked').map(function () {
        return $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text() + ':' + this.value;
    }).get().join();
    console.log(arr);
};
```

Comment: Hi! Tushar, Thank you for your reply. It works but I may have mislead you. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.map()` which create an array with `.join()` allow you to do that :

```
function DoRowSaveConfig(){
    var arr = $('tr:not(:first)').map(function(){
        var id = $.trim($(this).find('td').eq(1).text()); //1 == second column
        var value = $(this).find(':checked').val(); //Find the checked one
        return id + ':' + value; //Build an array of strings
    }).get()
    
    alert(arr.join(', ')); //Join them.
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ep6JE/1/

---

## Edit

After your edit, this code *should* work :

```
function DoRowSaveConfig(){
    var arr = $('row').map(function(){
        var id = this.id;
        var value = $(this).find(':checked').val(); //Find the checked one
        return id + ':' + value; //Build an array of strings
    }).get()
    
    alert(arr.join(', ')); //Join them.
}
```

Comment: Hi! Karl, Thank you for your reply. It works but I may have mislead you. Please see my edit.

Comment: @19eggs See my edit, i did not test it but i think it will work.

Comment: @19eggs can you make a fiddle, can't detect what's wrong : http://jsfiddle.net/ep6JE/2/

Comment: Hi ! I have updated your fiddle. We use DHTMLX and parse xml and it creates a grid (tables) and puts in the values from the xml to the <td> 
DHTMLX provides this to get the id of the row but no luck...var selId = grid.getSelectedId();

http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid:rows_manipulation  And many thanks for trying to take a look at it.

Comment: Thank you, Karl. I will try to sort out something.

Comment: Hi! Karl, I have a null value when the radio button is clicked for the first time...http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/ep6JE/10/

Comment: @19eggs Hi. your fiddle doesnt include you framework, hence i can't  really test it. But try changing `.click()` to `.change()`.

Comment: Hi! Karl.. an update..I changed the code slightly and made it work..here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/PYcH3/5/ and thanks again....